# function template: default first template argument to second

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, types, c++14

Is is possible to make the first template argument of a function template default to the second one if the first one is not specified?

Here is a small example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

template <typename ContainerOut, typename ContainerIn>
ContainerOut KeepNegatives(const ContainerIn& xs)
{
    ContainerOut result;
    auto itOut = std::inserter(result, std::end(result));
    auto isNegative = [](auto x){ return x < 0; };
    std::copy_if(std::begin(xs), std::end(xs), itOut, isNegative);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
    typedef std::list<int> IntList;

    IntVector intVector = { 1, -2, -3, 4 };
    IntList intList = { 1, -2, -3, 4 };

    auto intVec2 = KeepNegatives<IntVector>(intList);
    auto intList2 = KeepNegatives<IntList>(intVector);
    auto intVec3 = KeepNegatives<IntVector>(intVector);
}
```

This works, but what I want is, that the type of the return value of `KeepNegatives` (i.e. `ContainerOut`) is the same as the type of the input value (i.e. `ContainerIn`) in case `ContainerOut` is not specified. So that the following line of code would compile (right now it [does not](http://ideone.com/GuEFmo)) and return an `IntVector`.

```
    auto intVec4 = KeepNegatives(intVector);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply add an overload for this special case:

```
template <typename ContainerIn>
ContainerIn KeepNegatives(const ContainerIn& xs)
{
    return KeepNegatives<ContainerIn, ContainerIn>(xs);
}
```

This, however, can cause an ambiguity in your `intVec3` case. Here's one way around it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

template <typename ContainerOut, typename ContainerIn, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<ContainerOut, ContainerIn>::value>>
ContainerOut KeepNegatives(const ContainerIn& xs)
{
    ContainerOut result;
    auto itOut = std::inserter(result, std::end(result));
    auto isNegative = [](auto x){ return x < 0; };
    std::copy_if(std::begin(xs), std::end(xs), itOut, isNegative);
    return result;
}

template <typename ContainerIn>
ContainerIn KeepNegatives(const ContainerIn& xs)
{
    return KeepNegatives<ContainerIn, ContainerIn, void>(xs);
}


int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
    typedef std::list<int> IntList;

    IntVector intVector = { 1, -2, -3, 4 };
    IntList intList = { 1, -2, -3, 4 };

    auto intVec2 = KeepNegatives<IntVector>(intList);
    auto intList2 = KeepNegatives<IntList>(intVector);
    auto intVec3 = KeepNegatives<IntVector>(intVector);
    auto intVec4 = KeepNegatives(intVector);
}
```

[Live](http://rextester.com/RNZ58648)

Answer (score 3):

A better approach, taken by, e.g., [`std::experimental::make_array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array), is to not use `ContainerOut` as the return type directly; this allows you to specify a tag type as the default (`void` is a simple choice), and then compute the return type.

```
template <typename ContainerOut = void, typename ContainerIn,
          typename ret_t = std::conditional_t<std::is_void<ContainerOut>{},
                                              ContainerIn, ContainerOut>>
ret_t KeepNegatives(const ContainerIn& xs){
      // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine SFINAE with an overload as below:

```
template <typename ContainerOut, typename ContainerIn>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<ContainerOut, ContainerIn>::value, ContainerOut>
KeepNegatives(const ContainerIn& xs) {
    ContainerOut result;
    auto itOut = std::inserter(result, std::end(result));
    auto isNegative = [](auto x) { return x < 0; };
    std::copy_if(std::begin(xs), std::end(xs), itOut, isNegative);
    return result;
}

template <typename ContainerIn>
ContainerIn
KeepNegatives(const ContainerIn& xs) {
    ContainerIn result;
    auto itOut = std::inserter(result, std::end(result));
    auto isNegative = [](auto x) { return x < 0; };
    std::copy_if(std::begin(xs), std::end(xs), itOut, isNegative);
    return result;
}
```

and in `main`:

```
    auto intVec2 = KeepNegatives<IntVector>(intList);
    auto intList2 = KeepNegatives<IntList>(intVector);
    auto intVec3 = KeepNegatives(intVector);
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0af396a8b9c9714b)

Providing just a simple overload as:

```
template <typename ContainerIn>
ContainerIn KeepNegatives(const ContainerIn& xs) {...}
```

You'll get an ambiguous call to overloaded function, if the user provides explicitly the same template argument as:

```
auto intVec3 = KeepNegatives<IntVector>(intVector);
```

Comment: I was working exactly on this problem when you posted your answer :) Edited my answer to fix it